# (32) Ad-Hoc mode is not supported by this device. - 13.10 on i5 NUC

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10

Not sure if this is an Ubuntu issue or intel issue.  Any insights will be appreciated.

I have an intel NUC (D54250WYK) w/ intel 7260 wireless adapter and Ubuntu 13.10.

I can connect to my local wi-fi network without a problem, but can not create an ad-hoc network - (32) Ad-Hoc mode is not supported by this device.

Looks like the correct firmware is installed

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  683236 Jan 31 07:40 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  674628 Jan 31 07:47 iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
```

Answer (score 0):

from the sounds of the title your problem would appear to be hardware related however some reasearch i have done seems to point to an error with the internet connection not being shared with the device https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/Wireless-AC-7260-Ad-Hoc-Problem/td-p/1542738 however I am not experienced enough to know how one could solve the problem on ubuntu